# Flutter Sqfliteのnull Safetyについて

Tags: flutter

Flutter開発初心者です。

現在Sqfliteを使ってアプリにDatabaseを導入しようとしていて、以下のサイトを参考に構築しようとしています。

[FlutterのシンプルなSQFliteデータベースの例](https://ichi.pro/flutter-no-shinpuruna-sqflite-de-tabe-su-no-rei-252244950400913)
[Flutterでsqliteを使ったTodoアプリを作る](https://qiita.com/popy1017/items/7ada79b07281f4a8e544)

ですが、最近flutterがnull safetyを進めていて参考にしているサイト通りにコードを書いてもうまいように導入することができません。

問題となっているのは下記コード`DBProvider`の6行目の`Database _database`です。
エラー文は`Non-nullable instance field '_database' must be initialized.`となっていて初期化すればいいのはわかるのですが、どのようにコードを訂正したらいいのかがわかりません。
よろしくお願いします。

pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_riverpod: ^0.14.0+3
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  sqflite: ^2.0.0
```

DBProvider

```
class DBProvider {

  DBProvider._();

  static final DBProvider instance = DBProvider._();
  Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentDirectory.path, _dbName);
    return await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: _dbVersion,
      onCreate: _onCreate,
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE $_tableName (
    $_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    $_DateCreated TEXT NOT NULL,
    $_Note TEXT NOT NULL
    )''');
  }

  Future<int> insert(Memo memo) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert(_tableName, memo.toMap());
  }
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`late` をつける

```
late Database _database;
```

https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables

---

もしくは nullable にする

```
Database? _database;
```

この場合 `database` 関数も修正する必要があると思います。

```
// 修正例
Future<Database> get database async {
  if (_database != null) return _database!;
  _database = await _initDatabase();
  return _database!;
}
```